# Find the coordinates of a cuboid using list comprehension in Python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

`X`, `Y` and `Z` are the three coordinates of a cuboid.

Now X=1,Y=1, Z=1 and N=2.

I have to generate a list of all possible coordinates on a 3D grid where the sum of Xi + Yi + Zi is not equal to N. If X=2, the possible values of Xi can be 0, 1 and 2. The same applies to Y and Z.

I have written this below code so far, and it is giving the output as :

```
[[0, 0, 0]]
```

however the expected output is

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Below is my code, what is going wrong in my code?

```
[[x,y,z] for x in range(X) for y in range(Y) for z in range(Z) if x+y+z != N]
```

Comment: Try to `print range(1)` and you may see the problem

Answer (score 12):

`range` is actually a half-closed function. So, the ending value will not be included in the resulting range.

> If X=2, the possible values of Xi can be 0, 1 and 2

In your code, `range(X)` will give only `0` and `1`, if `X` is 2. You should have used `range(X + 1)`.

```
X, Y, Z, N = 1, 1, 1, 2
[[x,y,z] for x in range(X + 1) for y in range(Y + 1) for z in range(Z + 1) if x+y+z != N]

[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

You can write the same, with `itertools.product`, like this

```
X, Y, Z, N = 1, 1, 1, 2
from itertools import product
[list(i) for i in product(range(X + 1), range(Y + 1), range(Z + 1)) if sum(i) != N]

[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approch with [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and `list comprehension`:

```
In [91]: [list(l) for l in it.product([0,1], repeat=3) if sum(l) != 2]
Out[91]: [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    x = int(input())
    y = int(input())
    z = int(input())
    n = int(input())
    ans=[[i,j,k] for i in range(x+1) for j in range(y+1) for k in range(z+1) if i+j+k !=n]
    print(ans)
```

as range function doesn't include the ending value and stopped at (n-1)th position so if we use range(X) here it will result just 0 hence +1 should be used to print the list in lexicographic increasing order.

Comment: Please add explanation around your answer.

Comment: as range function doesn't include the ending value and stopped at (n-1)th position  so if we use range(X) here it will result just 0 hence +1 should be used to print the list in lexicographic increasing order.  @LordWilmore

Answer (score 1):

```
x = 1
y = 1
z = 2
n = 3

arr_3_D = []

for i in range(x+1):
    for j in range(y+1):
        for k in range(z+1):
            if i+j+k != n:
                arr = [i,j,k]
                arr_3_D.append(arr)


print(arr_3_D)
```

output: [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 2]]

Comment: Nice approach, well done. How can you approach this using a list comprehension rather than multiple loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
z = int(input())
n = int(input())
result = []

for i in range(x+1):
   for j in range(y+1):
       for k in range(z+1):
           if((x+y+z) != 1):
              arr = [i,j,k]
              result.append(arr)
print(result)
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Answer (score 0):

We have to use list comprehension and take a note that i should be in range 0 to x+1 as range function terminates on xth value and this is applicable for j and k also. Output expected should be in written in [i,j,k] format.

```
enter code here
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
z = int(input())
n = int(input())
i=0
#print(i)
j=0
#print(j)
k=0
#print(k) 
sum=x+y+z
output=[]
output=[[i,j,k] 
for i in range(0,x+1) 
for j in range(0,y+1) 
for k in range(0,z+1) if i+j+k !=  n] 
print(output)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. You can use the [edit] button to improve this answer to get more votes and reputation!